# Can anyone give a proof for ∠AOB =2∠APB of a circle

Tags: geometry, circles

We know that angle subtended by an arch is twice at the centre than anywhere else in the circle.  So if the angle at centre is AOB(say) so can anyone prove that angle on the circle subtended (say APB) by the same arch is half of it. Couldn't add diagram cos I'm new.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It would be helpful for questions of this nature, to include a drawing of what you are asking for.

Comment: This is a basic result, found in all geometry textbooks.

Comment: No its a specific case not give I was unable to post the image.

Comment: It's not twice as much in the center as "anywhere else in the circle"--it's twice as much as anywhere **on the circumference** of the circle. There is a different theorem for angles subtended at points inside the circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Note that $\angle AOC = 2 \angle APO$ and $\angle BOC = 2 \angle BPO$ because the triangles APO and BPO are isosceles. Thus, $\angle AOB = 2 \angle APB$.

Answer (score 0):

Connect $O$ to $A,B,P$.

Since $AOP.BOP$ and $OAB$ are isosceles, you ahve
$$\angle OPA =\angle OAP \\
\angle OPB =\angle OBP$$

Now, 
$$\angle POA + \angle POB+\angle AOB = 360^\circ = \angle OPA+\angle OAP +\angle POA + \angle OPB+\angle POB+\angle PBO$$

Canceling you get 
$$ \angle AOB  = \angle OPA+\angle OAP + \angle OPB+\angle PBO =2 \angle OPA+ 2 \angle OPB$$